# Yii2 framework facebook and google login using authclient not working

Tags: php, yii2

i have followed the instruction here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-authclient-authaction.html..  and it's not working for me.. i am using yii2  authclient for social website facebook and google login ...it's not working for me. i am attached  screen short .it's my login page

after clicking facebook or google button again the same page appeard in next new window pls see the image 
[image: Second image]

and also i am attached my full code 
this is on my controller.php

```
 public function actions()
    {

        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],

            'auth' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'],
            ],
        ];

    }
```

and this is on view page

```
 <?=
            yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
                'baseAuthUrl' => ['site/auth']
        ]); ?>
```

and this on my config directory main.php file

```
 'authClientCollection' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
        'clients' => [
               'facebook' =>[
                 'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',                      
                  'clientId' => '********',
                  'clientSecret' => '**********',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

..please help me..
Thanks

Comment: I too have a same problem To give some more explanation

The control is not transferred to  `yii\auth\client\AuthAction`
```
'auth' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                'successCallback' => [$this, 'successCallback'],
            ],
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that in your `behaviours()` you allow access to the action "auth" in your SiteController.php

So your `rules` should look something like:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'actions' => [ 'login', 'error', 'auth' ],
        'allow'   => true,
    ],
    [
        'actions' => [ 'logout', 'index' ],
        'allow'   => true,
        'roles'   => [ '@' ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer so that others may benefit.

Comment: HI @mathi: Please accept this answer as it solved your problem. "*..Thank you so much it's working fine now...... – @mathi*" And, if you don't know how to accept answer. Please go through it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.